# Laravel - how to get path name of file

Tags: php, file, laravel, filepath, pathname

In Laravel im using this code in my controller to get files from directory:

```
public function galleryImages($album) {

    $images = File::allFiles('gallery/'.$album);
    return View::make('galleryimages', ['images' => $images]);
}
```

and in my 'galleryimages' view is:

```
    @foreach($images as $image)

        <img src="???">  <-- how to get file url here?

    @endforeach
```

Now how can I get pathName of $image variable? Var_dump of $image is returning:

```
object(Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo)#247 (4) {
["relativePath":"Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo":private]=> string(0) "" 
["relativePathname":"Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo":private]=> string(11) "garden5.jpg" 
["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(25) "gallery/Album/garden5.jpg" 
["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(11) "garden5.jpg" }
```

I was trying $image->pathName, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use the getter method

```
$image->getPathname()
```

The Symfony class extends from `SplFileInfo`. You can find the reference to all its methods on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)